# Rendering Multiple Instances of the Same Component - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to render multiple instances of the same component. Here is the **component that will be repeated** (not my actual component, just an example):

```
import React from 'react';

function Repeated () {
    return (
         <div></div>
    )
}

export default Repeated;
```

And the **component that will repeat the other** (again, just an example):

```
import React from 'react';
import Repeated from './Component1';

function OtherComp () {
    return (
         <div>
             <Repeated />
             <Repeated />
             <Repeated />
             <Repeated />
         </div>
    )
}

export default OtherComp;
```

Is there any way I can add the "Repeated" component multiple times through something like a loop, instead of having to copy and paste the component multiple times? Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a new array of desired length and map it to the components. However, you have to add a key to every one of them or ignore a warning:

With warning:

```
return (
  <div>
    {Array(4).fill(<Repeated />)}
  </div>
)
```

Mapping to keys:

```
return (
  <div>
    {Array(4).fill(true).map((_, i) => <Repeated key={i} />)}
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Hi @JakubKotrs after rendering 4 times, let's suppose we want only 3  then how can I delete 4th one, in the same

Comment: You can make the `4` be a prop. ({ number }) => ...

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array for example and want to render each element as Repeat you can write

```
import React from 'react';
import Repeated from './Component1';

function OtherComp () {

    // get array via fetch or something else

    return (
         <div>
             { array.map(item => <Repeated key={a-unique-key} item={item} />) }
         </div>
    )
}

export default OtherComp;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the array of props you want to render via the Repeated components, provided that each of the rendered components has a **[unique key](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)**
The solution provided by @Jakub should work fine